# Усыпление потока, ожидание, продолжение

Tags: c#, таймер

Выполняю множество последовательных get-запросов. Слать запросы можно не чаще, чем через 340 мс.
Каждый раз, когда поток доходит до get-запроса, нужно проверять, прошло ли 340 мс с последнего запроса. Если да, то делаем запрос, если нет - ждем и продолжаем.
Я сделал таймер, который запускается каждый раз после get-запроса, по истечении 340 мс выключается и делает запрос доступным с помощью bool переменной.
Код:

```
static class RequestTimer
{
    public static bool requestIsAvailable;
    public static Timer requestTimer;

    static RequestTimer()
    {
        requestTimer = new Timer(340);
        requestTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        requestTimer.AutoReset = true;
        requestTimer.Enabled = false;
        requestIsAvailable = true;            
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        requestIsAvailable = true;
        requestTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

}

public class VkRequest
{
    public string GetResponse(string url, string namesValues)
    {
        string result = null;
        for (bool inLoop = true; inLoop == true; )
        {
            if (!RequestTimer.requestIsAvailable) continue;
            RequestTimer.requestIsAvailable = false;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                result = client.UploadString(url, namesValues);
                RequestTimer.requestTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
            inLoop = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что решение мягко говоря не очень. Про ожидание зацикливанием я вообще молчу.
Читал про события, делегаты, async, await и т.д. Глаза разбегаются и нe могу понять, что конкретно лучше применять в моем случае.
Хотелось бы услышать какие-нибудь советы)

Comment: А все запросы приходят в одном потоке или в разных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все запросы приходят в одном потоке, я бы сделал так:

```
Task cooldownTask = Task.CompletedTask;
Task currentRequest = null;
async Task<string> RequestAfterCooldown(string url, string namesValues)
{
    // дождаться окончания предыдущих заданий
    while (currentRequest != null)
        await currentRequest;

    // загеристрировать текущее задание
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> thisRequest = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    currentRequest = thisRequest.Task;

    try
    {
        // выдержать сделать паузу
        await cooldownTask;
        // установить новую паузу для следующего запроса
        cooldownTask = Task.Delay(340);

        // сделать сам запрос и вернуть ответ асинхронно
        using (var client = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
            return await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, namesValues);
    }
    finally
    {
        // завершить текущий запрос для тех, кто дожидается его снаружи
        currentRequest = null;
        thisRequest.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @your_mind: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло!